# hasChildNodes returns false but childNodes returns a node list as in the html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, nodes

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to add an onclick function to delete an element (book) that has been appended to its parent (bookshelf), however when trying to remove the element clicking on the trash icon I am told that my element is not a child of its parent. When I console.log hasChildNodes for the parent it returns false, but when I ask to print out childNodes I get a list of those children (books to be removed or kept). What can be the issue here?

```js
function deleteFunction(bookId) {
  var bookShelf = document.getElementById("bookshelf00"); 
  console.log(bookShelf.hasChildNodes); // returns false
  console.log(bookShelf.childNodes); // prints child elements 
  bookShelf.removeChild(document.getElementById(bookId)); // returns error message Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
}
```

This is the general structure of the HTML code I'm trying to work with, where I'm trying to remove the div with id "XIjqg9j6QOwC00M" and the subsequent elements:

```html
<div id="content" class="content-container">
  <h2>My Bookshelf</h2>
  <div class="bookShelf" id="bookshelfId">
    <div class="card marked" id="XIjqg9j6QOwC00M">
      <div class="card-icons" id="icon1">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can" id="TR-XIjqg9j6QOwC" onclick="deleteFunction(XIjqg9j6QOwC00M);"></i>
      </div>
      <div>element2</div>
      <div>element3</div>
      <div>element4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By clicking on the trash icon that is inside I call on the bookShelf element and expect to remove its child as identified by its id. In this example I want to remove the element with the id "XIjqg9j6QOwC00M",  which although I can see in the child node list for the bookshelf element, the bookShelf hasChildNodes function returns false and also doesn't allow me to remove it giving this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Comment: there is no element with id = "bookshel00"

Comment: bookShelf.hasChildNodes is a FUNCTION ... how is console logging a function outputting false? it should output a function

Comment: probably just a type here, but i think it should be `onclick="deleteFunction('XIjqg9j6QOwC00M');"` instead of `onclick="deleteFunction(XIjqg9j6QOwC00M);"`

Comment: @Michael - I think that's not a typo, I think that's the OP's problem

Comment: @dokokos my bad I missed that line with the bookshelf element when typing the question - I have corrected it now.

Comment: @JaromandaX the hasChildNodes function returns a boolean value only.

Comment: yes, thank you for educating me on that ... however, the code you posted WONT even RUN the function, so, what that function returns is completely irrelevant until such time you run the function. Would you agree?